# Is there a way to programatically change database sources in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have two databases I need to work with, one oracle on a remote box, and one mysql on my local box.  The oracle DB only has SOME of the data I need to work with, so I set up my models to use the mysql database by default, and the few models I needed to work with oracle, I did:

```
     establish_connection "oracle_database"
```

Which worked just fine.

Unfortunately, I've just been informed that I can't rely on the remote oracle database being available.  My new requirement is that my system needs to be able to use the oracle database (if available), or, if it isn't, needs to use a local database that would have the same sorts of tables/columns/etc.

This seems like something Rails wouldn't actually be built to support?  Am I going to be stuck manually editing my database.yml file to change "oracle_database" to sometimes point at the remote DB, and sometimes point at the local one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use begin rescue to catch an exception while establishing connection to remote server, like this

```
begin
  establish_connection "oracle_database"
rescue Exception => e
  logger.warn "Connecting to local database due to exception #{e.to_s}"
  establish_connection "local_database"
end
```

Comment: Except...of course...the exception I'm getting is a timeout one when it can't find the other database, and it's taking too long to timeout to be feasible (back to my if statement, I guess). BUT, this still technically does what I hoped it would, so thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think you should look at https://github.com/mixonic/ShardTheLove

Comment: I'm not entirely sure...  I won't know in my code whether I want the remote or the local database...it's just sometimes there won't BE a remote database, and I don't want my rails app to explode...  I'm not sure the shards will handle that gracefully (I still have to explicitly say "I want to use database X" it looks like...)

Answer (score 0):

This isn't as robust as I would like, but for now I found out I could do a work around with config variables:

```
 if APP_CONFIG["use_remote"]
      establish_connection "oracle_database"
 else
      establish_connection "local_database" 
 end
```

And then I can set the config var to be "true" or "false" my config file.  I'd RATHER it change automatically based on if the database is available, but for now this is working for me...